# Javascript library d3 call function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am not able to understand how d3.call() works and when and where to use that. [Here](http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/axes/) is the tutorial link that I'm trying to complete.

Can someone please explain specifically what this piece is doing

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
              .scale(xScale)
              .orient("bottom");

svg.append("g").call(xAxis);
```

Comment: the link you provided explains what `call()` does

Comment: Yea, but still I am not able to get what  svg.append("g") .call(xAxis);  is doing  :(

Comment: see https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_call

Answer (score 133, accepted):

I think the trick here is to understand that xAxis is a function that generates a bunch of SVG elements. In fact it is the function returned by `d3.svg.axis()`. The scale and orient functions are just part of the chaining syntax (read more of that here: http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/chaining-methods/).

So `svg.append("g")` appends an SVG group element to the svg and returns a reference to itself in the form of a selection (same chain syntax at work here). When you use `call` on a selection you are calling the function named `xAxis` on the elements of the selection `g`. In this case you are running the axis function, `xAxis`, on the newly created and appended group, `g`.

If that still doesn't make sense, the syntax above is equivalent to:

```
xAxis(svg.append("g"));
```

or:

```
d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(xScale)
      .orient("bottom")(svg.append("g"));
```

Comment: how would one edit the G elements of an svg.axis() ? I have labels that bleed into each other and I want to apply a transformation to them. But I can't seem to access those elements

Comment: Check the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12825630/assign-ids-to-individual-axis-text-elements/12849772#12849772 After you have selected the text or tick elements you should be able to apply transforms if you want.

Comment: Is there any difference doing one or the other to call xAxis?

Comment: This explains well the `.call()` method in general. It doesn't explain the consequences of calling the axis object in particular. And it doesn't come close to justifying the surreal situation of an axis object behaving like **both an object and a function**. Why in the world do that? Okay so the docs say calling it [renders the axis](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis/blob/master/README.md#_axis). Is that better than giving the axis object a .render() method? Wouldn't that support a much more straightforward `xAxis.scale(...).orient(...).render(...)`

Comment: From the docs in selection call: "The only difference is that selection.call always returns the selection and not the return value of the called function, name."

Answer (score 30):

What the accepted answer left out IMO is that `.call()` is a [D3 API function](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/v1.4.1/README.md#selection_call) and not to be confused with [Function.prototype.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

`selection.call(function[, arguments…])`

> Invokes the specified function exactly once, passing in this selection along with any optional arguments. Returns this selection. This is equivalent to invoking the function by hand but facilitates method chaining. For example, to set several styles in a reusable function:

Now say:

```
d3.selectAll("div").call(name, "John", "Snow");
```

This is roughly equivalent to:

```
name(d3.selectAll("div"), "John", "Snow");
```

where name is a function, for example

```js
function name(selection, first, last) {
  selection
      .attr("first-name", first)
      .attr("last-name", last);
}
```

The only difference is that selection.call *always returns the selection and not the return value of the called function*, name.

Comment: This indeed very important info!! Thx