# Assign IDs to Individual Axis Text Elements

Tags: d3.js, label, axis

I'm using d3.axis() to create axis labels and tick marks that I'd like to refer to individually using d3.select("#axisTextIDValue") but I see no way to manipulate the id attribute of individual text elements in an axis. Does anyone know how to create ID values for the ticks or text elements of an axis?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While the other answer does explain how to select the ticks, if you want to assign unique ids to generated elements like these, you can do so using subselections by giving an id or class to the g that you've called for your axis and then setting ids for the child text elements based on their array position:

```
 d3.select("svg").append("g").attr("id", "axisG").call(axis);
 d3.select("#axisG").selectAll("text").attr("id", function(d,i) {return "axisText" + i});

 d3.select("#axisText0").node(); //demonstrates selectability
```

That said, this probably isn't a very good idea and there are better ways to deal with ticks/labels/voronoi/etc that are generated on-the-fly by D3, but I wanted to make sure to put an answer up here just in case somebody is looking for how to do this kind of thing.

Comment: Works perfect for my selenium tests!

Answer (score 3):

The tricky part of this is that you will not know ahead of time what ticks you have or how many (unless you use tickValues property on your axis).

In general you can class the group you create your axis in and use that as a basis for further selections. For example

```
var axisGroup = parent.append('g')
                .attr('class', 'axis')

axisGroup.call(axis);
```

I believe the tick lines get assigned the "tick" class so you can select all the tick lines:

```
axisGroup.selectAll('.tick');
```

Or all the text labels:

```
axisGroup.selectAll('text');
```